# Amazon Lex API checksum error

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto3, amazon-lex

When using `put_intent` to update an existing intent, I provide the checksum in this way:

```
checksum = lex_client.get_intent(name=intent_name, version='$LATEST')['checksum']
```

and then use the checksum with `put_intent`:

```
lex_client.put_intent(
        name=name,
        slots=slots,
        sampleUtterances=utterances,
        checksum=checksum
    )
```

The exception thrown is:

> botocore.errorfactory.BadRequestException: An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the PutIntent operation: The fulfillment is not valid for intent 'TotalWasteForItem'. Specify another fullfillment.

Intent does not have multiple versions, `'$LATEST'` is the only one. Checksum is returned normally and is of type `str`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`put_intent` requires the `fulfillmentActivity` be passed:

> fulfillmentActivity (dict) --
>   Describes how the intent is fulfilled. For example, after a user provides all of the information for a pizza order, fulfillmentActivity defines how the bot places an order with a local pizza store.
>
> You might configure Amazon Lex to return all of the intent information to the client application, or direct it to invoke a Lambda function that can process the intent (for example, place an order with a pizzeria).
>
> type (string) -- **[REQUIRED]**
>   How the intent should be fulfilled, either by running a Lambda function or by returning the slot data to the client application.
>
> ...

You can provide this to simply response with the parameters. This is good for testing.

```
fulfillmentActivity={'type': 'ReturnIntent'},
```

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/lex-models.html#LexModelBuildingService.Client.put_intent